# Picasso 2.71828 load uri issue

Tags: android, imageview, picasso

See below codes

```
Picasso.get().load(crop_image_uri.toString())
.placeholder(R.drawable.header_img).into(app_bar_image);
```

It will not load image, but if using below code

```
app_bar_image.setImageURI(crop_image_uri);
```

it will be fine and load image properly.

Below is crop_image_uri

```
E/crop_image_uri: file:///data/user/0/com.example.yaniu.viewpagertransitiondemo/files/song_app_bar_image.jpg
```

Why Picasso not load uri file??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

find the problem, using implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828' instead of importing picasso aar file, that will fix the issue. Could you someone tell me what difference between implementation and importing aar file?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
File f = new File(uri)

Picasso.with(context).load(f).into(imageView);
```

or

```
Picasso.with(context)).load(uri).into(imageView);
```

Comment: no luck, neither .load(file) nor .load(uri) is working.